# How to migrate dialogflow from V2beta1 to V2?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I can't find a way to migrating from dialogflow V2beta1 to V2, and I can't find the client access token. Is there anyone can help me? I'm new to dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

You don't need client access token now.. you can use the service account key. You can find it from the Agent settings. Click on the service account name and you will be redirected to the GCP console, locate the same service account and download as JSON to use in the Dialogflow API.

[image: service account dialogflow]

[image: download service account]